# Binding to custom control inside DataTemplate for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, custom-controls, itemscontrol

I have a problem with bindings for `DataTemplate` based on defined `DataType` in `ItemsControl`, when I want to bind to my **custom user control**.

For demonstration purposes, I've created simple **Item class** example, where I have collection of items like this:

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound { get; set; } 
}
```

In my **ViewModel** I create such collection, and expose it (with one item for comparison separately):

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    private Item _exampleItem;

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(new[] { new Item { ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound = "Me" }, new Item { ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound = "MySelf" }, new Item { ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound = "Ich" }, });
        ExampleItem = Items.LastOrDefault();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public Item ExampleItem
    {
        get { return _exampleItem; }
        set { _exampleItem = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

My **custom user control** is defined like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfDataTemplate.ItemRowUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="40" d:DesignWidth="300"
         x:Name="ItemRowControl" DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    <Grid Background="Yellow" Height="40">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" Foreground="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

...and it has one `DependencyProperty` in **code behind**:

```
public partial class ItemRowUserControl : UserControl
{
    public ItemRowUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ItemName", typeof (string), typeof (ItemRowUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public string ItemName
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(ItemNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemNameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I try to bind to property of Item in DataTemplate for ItemsControl, which I'm doing in **MainWindow** like this (note: I have dummy converter for debugging purposes only, returning value back, and nothing more):

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <my:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <my:MyDummyConverter x:Key="MyDummyConverter" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:Item}">
                <my:ItemRowUserControl ItemName="{Binding ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound, Converter={StaticResource MyDummyConverter}}"  />
                <!--<Grid Background="Pink">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound, Converter={StaticResource MyDummyConverter}}" Foreground="Black" Height="30" />
                </Grid>-->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <my:ItemRowUserControl ItemName="{Binding DataContext.ExampleItem.ItemNameToBeSureWhatPropertyIsBound, ElementName=MyWindow, Converter={StaticResource MyDummyConverter}}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Now, in case I bind to my custom ItemRowUserControl, the value I get into converter (and I see the same in Debug Output) is ItemRowUserControl itself. But if I bind to commented out code, everything works fine. Why is that, and how can I have custom control for DataTemplate so that bindings (offered by intellisense) will work? On the side note: binding to my ItemRowUserControl in grid row 1 (at the bottom) works fine, so I guess control is set to work as expected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you explicitly set the `DataContext` of your UserControl to itself:

```
DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

Remove that assignment and write the `ItemName` binding like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

or like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName, ElementName=ItemRowControl}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works as expected. Can you explain the RelativeSource part of the binding, please? Binding with ElementName in your answer, makes sense to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Please refer to [online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) on MSDN. In either case, the UserControl instance is set as the source object of the binding.

Comment: @JanezLukan that means relatively lookup in control tree until it finds control of type `UserControl` and lookup will be upwards because it says `AncestorType`

Comment: @Clemens: What if I want to set a DataContext to my custom UserControl? Is there a way to handle that?

Comment: @Clemens thanks so much! This issue has been plaguing me for a few hours now.