# UserControl Data Binding Not working in a ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, user-controls

I have a `ListBox` where the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` needs to be a `UserControl`. The problem is that the `UserControl` data binding is not working.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <local:MyUserControl Data1="{Binding Path=MyData}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

When I do this `Data1` stays NULL.  If I would remove the binding and just send some value down like this;

```
<local:MyUserControl Data1="Bob" />
```

The `UserControl` works (although now is useless due to hard coding).

Here is the declaration of `Data1` in the `UserControl`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty
    Data1Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Data1", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));
public string Data1
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(Data1Property); }
    set { SetValue(Data1Property, value); }
}
```

One last note, if I pull out the `UserControl` from `ListBox` and bind it with some other data it works correctly.

Comment: Did you explicitly set the UserControl's DataContext in its XAML or code behind? You shouldn't do that, because it breaks the Binding to the control's properties (unless you set their source objects explicitly). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27834461/1136211

Comment: Enable WPF tracing first and see what errors/warnings it outputs. Visual studio - tools/options/debugging/output window. If a binding is not working that's where I look first.

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=TwoWay` in the ItemsSource binding is pointless. It has no effect here.