# XAML GridView ItemTemplate not binding to control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a *GridView* with an ItemTemplate that holds a Custom control:

```
<GridView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Ubicaciones.Ubicaciones}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ctr:HabitacionControl
                Width="70"
                Height="140"
                Ubicacion="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And here is my custom user control:

```
<UserControl
        x:Class="MySln.Mucama.Controls.HabitacionControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:MySln.Mucama.Controls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DesignHeight="200"
        d:DesignWidth="97">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:HabitacionControlVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <RelativePanel>
            <Image x:Name="Puerta" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Puerta.jpg"
                   Grid.RowSpan="5"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Ubicacion.StrNombreMesa,FallbackValue=####}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Foreground="AliceBlue"
                       FontWeight="ExtraBold"
                           RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And its code behind:

```
public sealed partial class HabitacionControl : UserControl
{
    public HabitacionControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyClass Ubicacion
    {
        get { return (MyClass)GetValue(UbicacionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UbicacionProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Ubicacion.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UbicacionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Ubicacion", typeof(MyClass), typeof(HabitacionControl), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnUbicacionChanged)));

    private static void OnUbicacionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Now I need to bind each Ubicaciones.Ubicaciones to the Ubicación property of my Customcontrol.

At run time my gridview generates all my items, but binding to its **Ubicacion** property never happens.

There aren't any warnings in the output window.

What I'm missing? Or doing wrong?

Comment: *Never* explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl, regardless of what they tell you in online tutorials or blog posts.

Comment: @Clemens Gonna disagree with the closure.  This question's UserControlViewModel and the pseudo-DataContext sets it enough apart.  It's also a nice, clear example that I can reference for people who are doing the exact same thing.  I'll dupe close the `DataContext = this;` questions to your example :)

Comment: It doesn't matter much if you set the DataContext of a UserControl to a local view model or to itself. The important fact is that doing so prevents that the control inherits the DataContext from its parent. So see [Binding to custom control inside DataTemplate for ItemsControl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27834461/1136211) for how to write the Bindngs in the UserControl's XAML.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My my, look at this here:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:HabitacionControlVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Someone sold you a bill of dirty, filthy, goods. Probably one of those jerks who run around telling people `DataContext = this;` is a good idea.

Sorry, tangent.  Now look at this:

```
<ctr:HabitacionControl 
    Width="70" 
    Height="140" 
    Ubicacion="{Binding}"/>
```

What is that I'm seeing?  Is that a pseudo-DataContext property?  That's a pseudo-DataContext property.  The problem is that the `Binding` works against the object within the DataContext of the `HabitacionControl` **not its parent**.  And what's the DataContext of the `HabitacionControl`?

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:HabitacionControlVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And that's why you don't create view models for your UserControls.  You have broken how data binding works.  The view model must flow down the visual tree through the DataContext.  When you interrupt this flow, you get fail.

Let me ask you--does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  **No.** It has a `Text` property that *you* bind to.  How do you bind to it?  Your view model flows into `TextBox.DataContext`, thus allowing you to bind properties of your view model to properties exposed on the TextBox.

There are other hacky ways to get around this, but the best solution is to not get yourself into this situation in the first place.

You need to ditch that `HabitacionControlVM` and expose DependencyProperties on the surface of your UserControl that your view model can bind against, providing whatever your UserControl needs in order to function.  Place your UI logic in the codebehind of `HabitacionControl`.

No, this doesn't break MVVM.  UI logic is fine in the codebehind.

If your `HabitacionControlVM` is performing heavy lifting that really shouldn't be in the codebehind, then just refactor it into classes that your codebehind calls into.

People think the UserControlViewModel anti-pattern is how it should be done.  It really isn't.  Good luck.

Comment: Just an issue, My control now have access to  each _Ubicacion_, but My DP, never fires it's  _PropertyChangedCallback_ delegate.

Comment: I think there's some sound advice in this answer, but I find it hard to discern through the snark/sarcasm. I wish it was written as straightforward advice :/