# Double Binding in c# uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, uwp

I have a problem. I created 2 controls for my application: a BottomMenu control and ResultBox. ResultBox is contained in BottomMenu so the order goes like this: Page -> BottomMenu -> ResultBox. I created a dependency property in ResultBox called Result of type string.

```
    public ResultBox()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property used to store the result of the calculation
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Result",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ResultBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// String holding the text assigned to the Result
    /// </summary>
    public string Result
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ResultProperty);
        set => SetValue(ResultProperty, value);
    }
```

The binding is as follows:

```
<TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}"
                        Text="{Binding Result}"/>
```

Then I created identical dependency property in the BottomMenu so thatcan set it directly from the page.

```
    public BottomMenu()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Property used to store the result of the calculation
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResultProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Result",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(BottomMenu),
        new PropertyMetadata(null)
        );

    /// <summary>
    /// String holding the text assigned to the Result
    /// </summary>
    public string Result
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ResultProperty);
        set => SetValue(ResultProperty, value);
    }
```

And binding:

```
<local:ResultBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 10"
                        Result="{Binding Result}"
                        />
```

Unfortunately, the text only shows up if I directly input it in the declaration of ResultBox. When I do the double binding and input it in the page,

```
<local:BottomMenu Grid.Row="2"                              
                            Result="13"/>
```

it doesn't work. I'm learning binding and I'd like to know where I'm doing it wrong, or if it's even the proper way to do this thing.

Edit: Binding in ResultBox should't contain Source, fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost never use `this.DataContext = this`; inside controls. Always define the `DataContext` at the top level page and let it flow down to each control along the way.

So first remove

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

You have defined the dependency property `Result` correctly. To bind the `TextBlock`'s `Text` to it, you can name your control and use `ElementName` binding, or more efficiently (UWP only), use `x:Bind` like the following

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBlockStyle}" Text="{x:Bind Result, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Same goes to this

```
<local:ResultBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 10" Result="{x:Bind Result, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here, instead of setting `this.DataContext = this;`, we should use `(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;` like the following:

```
public BottomMenu()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;
}
```

```
public ResultBox()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    (this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this; 
}
```

In the code above we don’t set the data context of the user control, we set the data context of the first child in the user control. After this, the `ResultBox` inside `BottomMenu` can inherit down the data context from `BottomMenu` and its `Result` property can be set properly. For more info, please see Jerry Nixon's blog:
 [Walkthrough: Two-way binding inside a XAML User Control](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/07/solved-two-way-binding-inside-user.html).

Comment: Note this *works*, but it's not the recommended approach in UWP. Setting `DataContext` like this breaks the flow of the data, and will cause side effects. Not to mention performance wise it's worse than using `x:Bind`.

Comment: If interested have a look at the discussions about `DataContext = this` from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729083/xaml-gridview-itemtemplate-not-binding-to-control/44729258#44729258).

Comment: @JustinXL I'd agree with that we should not set `DataContext = this` on `UserControl`. That's why we set the data context of the first child in the user control with `(this.Content as FrameworkElement).DataContext = this;`. And this will solve the data context inheritance issue in above question. This might not a best solution in UWP, but I think it's still a alternative way when using binding inside UserControl.

Comment: Well that's basically the same thing right? If you set it to `this` it will then go down to `this.Content`. It's definitely an alternative, just not a good one IMHO. Generally, even without `x:Bind`, `ElementName` binding should be used instead of this pattern. :)

Comment: This solution might be a little tricky and hard to understand when comparing with the `ElementName` one. The key point here is that we need the data context inheritance at the `UserControl` level so we should not set the data context of the user control. However, inside the user control, we are always focus on the custom DP (or some existing properties of `UserControl`) not the data context outside, so we can use the data context of the first child (usually a container) to perform binding. I'd think this is also a brilliant solution, it's not bad than using `ElementName`.