# MVVM DataBinding OK in Designer, not at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

Why can databinding be seen working in the designer:
[Click to show image: Databinding seems OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to7Zw.jpg)
But runtime shows nothing?
[Click to show image: No Data, no usercontrol?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTurP.jpg)

Outline code structure:

ViewModelBase :  baseclass inheriting from INotofyPropertychanged

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;
        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

SiteViewModel :  Model class with Id/Name/Description Properties

```
 public class SiteViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _SiteID;
    private string _Name;
    private string _Description;

    public int SiteID
    {
        get { return _SiteID; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _SiteID, value); }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Name, value); }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return _Description; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Description, value); }
    }
}
```

SitesViewModel:  ObservableCollection of SiteViewModel

```
 public class SitesViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<SiteViewModel> _AllSites;

    public ObservableCollection<SiteViewModel> AllSites {
        get { return _AllSites; }
        set { SetProperty<ObservableCollection<SiteViewModel>>(ref _AllSites, value); }
    }

    public SitesViewModel()
    {
        AllSites = new ObservableCollection<SiteViewModel>();
        for (int count = 1; count <= 3; count++)
        {
            AllSites.Add(new SiteViewModel { SiteID = count, Name = "Test" + count.ToString(), Description = "Site:" + count.ToString() } ); 
        }
    }
}
```

SiteManagerControl : UserControl with a SitesViewModel property _AllSites

```
public partial class SiteManagerControl : UserControl
{
    private SitesViewModel _AllSites;
    public SitesViewModel AllSites
    {
        get { return _AllSites; } //<-- Breakpoint not hit!
        set {
            if (_AllSites != value)
            { _AllSites = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AllSites");
            }}
    }

    public SiteManagerControl(){
        _AllSites = new SitesViewModel();}
```

(XAML can be seen in the first linked image above, Note the breakpoint not hit line in the above).  The user control is hosted in a Tabcontrol that is part of an ObservableCollection.  I don't think this is an issue in the databinding.  Will post the code for the tabs if needed.

There are no errors in the Debug Output window to indicate why the databinding is failing.

Comment: Post the XAML of your TabControl. What is its DataContext?

Comment: UserControls should be designed for your models or your view models. You should NOT design a view model for your UserControl. Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel? No, and there's a very good reason why. For more details [read this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729258/1228)  Also, you can always use tools like Snoop to examine your bindings at runtime. It would have shown you that the parent view model was inherited by your user control, which replaced the SitesViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Your listview DataContext Data binding is with object from class(SitesViewModel)
This class has property named (AllSites) that has oveservable collection property named (AllSites) as well.

so I think you have to fix the ItemSource binding in the list view like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding AllSites.AllSites}"
```

Comment: Alas no joy, this just breaks the binding in the designer.  Still no binding in the runtime.  I can see that {Binding AllSites.AllSites} only has one property (.Count).

Answer (score 0):

Will's comment (thanks!) above pointed me in the right direction: Changed MainWindow.xaml to contain:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:SitesViewModel}">
        <uc:SitesView></uc:SitesView>
</DataTemplate>
```

Also followed this : http://codingtales.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/creating-complete-tabbed-interface-in.html to rework my tab interface