# MVVM correct flow of events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm

I'm somewhat new to MVVM but I have had my hands on it for some time now.  Unfortunately, perusing the internet there seems to be no solid consensus on the best way for an application to process events in MVVM.  I have a situation pictured below in which I am combining two controls - each in a self contained xml that i'm going to call two separate views: ListBox and ButtonPanel.

[image: MasterView]

How should the direction of events flow then?  Let's take a scenario where upon clicking my button in the button panel, a file is created in the list box control.  Would the flow of events in image one or in image two be more appropriate?

Event Flow One - Communicating ViewModel to ViewModel:
[image]

Event Flow Two - All Front end classes don't communicate.  All messages are passed via the Application Layer (whatever is hooked up to the back end: db, processing functions, etc..)
[image]

Please note - i didn't picture it but I am using ICommand to pass the click event from my Button Panel View to my Button Panel View Model.

And lastly once again my question is: How should events be processed in an MVVM flow.  Are either of my graphics appropriate?

*** **EDIT IN RESPONSE TO Ed Plunkett's ANSWER** ***

Is this then the sort of event flow you would expect:
[image]

Is this closer to the correct architecture?

In this image the << >> between ViewModels are actually properties being exposed to the views, and the majority of the events are being handled as bindings there in the view.

My concerns with this are:

1. The Master ViewModel is now responsible for collecting information from both views.  I'm not sure how to handle this without using mediator/messenger -  that is without tightly coupling my parent view model to the child.  Either i'd have to register events by name in all view models, or make specific callbacks by name for each of the viewmodels, so a mediator would still be necessary to achieve loosely coupled design (which is the entire advantage of using MVVM).
2. Even if i'm wrong in point 1 - what is the advantage of using a parent child ViewModel relationship?
3. Concerning the point of ViewModels don't know what a button or a panel is:

   I agree.  You can ignore my naming of classes here.  I've just done it this way to make the question easy to understand - named classes so that an onlooker knows what control is being handled in each.  My actual classes are named based on the data they handle, not the component.

Comment: The view should hold the instance of the file view model and the button panel view model. Thus removing the need for messaging between the 2.

Comment: Side note, because "FileListBoxViewModel" triggers me... UserControls should be designed for your models or your view models. You should NOT design a view model for your UserControl. Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel? **No,** and there's a very good reason why. For a real life example of this anti-pattern and why it fails so hard read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729258/1228). Also, `DataContext = this;` is a cancer in MVVM.  Avoid both of these and you're going to be better off than most new folks.

Comment: @Will - agree mostly.  I just named everything that way to keep my question succinct.  However, I think that having a UserControl that implements a specific ViewModel really depends on the complexity of the Control/View.  It just doesn't seem sensible to me to stick a large amount of logic in my parent ViewModel if it is inherrent to my control and can be better organized in it's own control specific VM.  Is there some fatal flaw i'm missing?

Comment: "what is the advantage of using a parent child ViewModel relationship?" -- Keep It Simple. You have it exactly backwards: You're asking me to justify doing things in a simple, clear, straightforward way. That's the default. It needs no justification. What's your justification for messaging?

Comment: Concrete justification, not theoretical. WPF is hard enough to learn without going out of your way to complicate and confuse things. For perspective, I'm the main developer on a large WPF application, several years old, with dozens of views and viewmodels. We run our entire business on it. So I'm not just offering opinions based on a white paper or something, I have some real experience with WPF.

Comment: Remember--MVVM != no codebehind. *"It just doesn't seem sensible to me to stick a large amount of logic in my parent ViewModel if it is inherrent to my control"* Absolutely correct!  UI logic lives in your user control's codebehind. Your view models should express the current application's state via its properties and accept commands from the user. It's up to your controls (via built-in functionality or through code you write in your UI) to interpret the state and display it to the user, and take in user actions and convey them to VM commands.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case: One viewmodel.

The button invokes a command that it gets from a property of the viewmodel.

The viewmodel also has a property something like

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeFileViewModelClass> Files { /* INPC stuff */ }
```

The button has no idea what the command does. Presumably the command tells the viewmodel to create a file, and add a new instance of `SomeFileViewModelClass` to `Files`.

Meanwhile, back in the XAML, the `ListBox` is using `Files` as an items source:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
    ...
```

...so the listbox will automatically update to show the new file.

If you want your button panel to have its own viewmodel (you almost certainly don't, and even if you do, don't call it a "button panel viewmodel"; viewmodels don't know what buttons *or* panels even are) and your file list to have its own viewmodel (maybe), make those kind of things *child viewmodels* of the main viewmodel. The main viewmodel creates them and manages relationships between them.

```
public FilesViewModel FileList { /* INPC stuff */ }
```

Maybe `FileList` now owns `ObservableCollection<SomeFileViewModelClass> Files` -- but if that's *all* it owns, it isn't a viewmodel. Just put that `Files` property on the main viewmodel.

```
<Button Content="Create File" Command="{Binding CreateFileCommand}" />

<!-- ... snip -->

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileList.Files}" />
```

Maybe `CreateFileCommand` should be a property of `FilesViewModel`, if that even exists.

Keep it as simple as possible, but no simpler.

Do not design a UI and then create one viewmodel for each thing in the UI. That's backwards. Controls don't have viewmodels.

Design viewmodels to model the things your application needs to deal with. Parent and child viewmodels, based on the actual relationships between the actual stuff (personally, I prefer to model the smallest "leaf node" things first, then work my way into the center). Then add views to display them to the user. This takes a little getting used to, but it pays off.

**Your viewmodels are "The Program"**. You write views to display the program to the user and let the user talk to the program. You write models/database/file access/whatever to let the program store and retrieve state.

Your "All messages are passed via the Application Layer" idea is not MVVM.

Your second thing with the yellow "mediator/messenger" box is close to correct, but there's no "mediator/messenger"; parents talk to children. If a child will need to know something about a sibling, you would manage that by having the children expose events. The parent can wire up event handlers among the children -- to do it quick and dirty, you can always handle `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` on a child, but specialized events are often preferred. Dependency injection is another option but it's easy to end up writing classes with a maze of dependencies. DI can turn into an antipattern, and multi-colored block diagrams of the information flow in user interfaces is a leading indicator that it's about to.

Comment: I think he just gave a simple example. Agreed that a VM for each control is not right, I don't think that's what he was going for. Looks closer to something like Visual Studio. The Class View and the Text View would most certainly be different VMs and the main window would be a 3rd. That is what I based my answer on.

Comment: I just put in an edit to Ed's response in the...OP...OQ?...OP? (not sure on the proper StackOverflow nomenclature).

Answer (score -1):

Your case is simplified, but you'd really have a "ListBox View" that contains a ListBox and a "Button View" that contains the button. Both of those views would be child views of the "Main Window View".

I'd have to disagree with Ed here and say I would never combine VMs... that breaks the single responsibility paradigm that MVVM tries to install.

The standard MVVM way of having VMs communicate is through the messenger / event aggregator paradigm.

So i'd vote for workflow #1. ALMOST...

VM's should NOT send a message to another VM to write to a DB, etc. That's what models are for.

If you want to abstract away the DB, the standard way to do that is to define a IDataProvider type interface and use DI to inject it into VMs that need it. You'll find as your app gets larger and more complicated, DI and MVVM are a match made in heaven.

MVVM + DI + Messenger all work together beautfully and keep everything seperate and organized.

Personally I like to keep V <-> VMs 1:1 with no code behind, but that's the super purist definition of MVVM.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I don't think you really mean you are just plopping 2 controls on a form and making each a VM, I wouldn't do that. Break the UI into logical "regions" and each "region" would have a VM and a V.

Comment: *"The standard MVVM way of having VMs communicate is through the messenger / event aggregator paradigm."* -- I wouldn't add that complexity unless it's going to pay off in some clear and substantial way. I don't see how it's violating any "single responsibility paradigm" if a thing that owns a list of files (for example) models that by having a property that's a list of file viewmodels, but maybe we're talking past each other.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I meant that a VM that owns a list of files would obviously manage that list for view binding (i.e. the Solution View in VS). I wouldn't have a VM that managed the Solution View *AND* the Code Editor view in of itself (your combined VM). I'd have the solution view VM, the code editor VM and the main window VM that manages the child VMs, but doesn't manage the stuff *inside* the child VMs. Main window would manage stuff like layout, ribbon bar, etc. At least thats the way I do it :). If it's a small throw away app I wouldn't even bother with MVVM, the spin up time ain't worth it.

Comment: Huh. I have snippets to create INPC properties and VMs -- goes pretty quick. I'd hate to have to do WPF winforms style. I can't imagine why or how you'd have a vm manage stuff *inside* its child vms anyway; classes are classes.

Comment: @SledgeHammer - so you would pick up the messenger events in the FileListBox Model?  That means that event flow would be one way in that MVVM set - Model>>ViewModel>>View.  Correct?

Comment: @JamieMarshall the way I have my MVVM framework set up, I register the messenger interface with the DI engine and any VM can automatically get it injected if I add a IMessenger messenger to the constructor. Any VM can post a message and any VM can listen to any type of message. VM's just subscribe to messages of type T.

Comment: @JamieMarshall messenger is mostly used to communicate between VMs. You shouldn't be sending messages to a model. So workflow is VM#1 posts message of type MyMessage and VM#2 subscribes to messages of type MyMessage and gets notified when any come through. Messenger is one way async fire & forget so you don't get into a deadlock. If you want 2 way communication you add a "MyMessageResponse". You can have multiple message subscribers, so there isn't the concept of a response per say. Who did the message come from? What do you do if you get 5 responses, etc.

Comment: @JamieMarshall -- another method to do a "response" message to add a callback in the one way message instead of using a 2nd message, but since the callback wouldn't be async (unless you make it that way), you can get deadlocked.

Comment: @JamieMarshall -- for DB stuff, build a self standing data layer and define an interface and then use DI to inject your IDataLayer into the VMs. Then each VM can call into through the interface without relying on another VM. Making one VM responsible for DB stuff, you'll get into a situation where one VM has to do it slightly different and you end up with a bunch of flags, etc.