# MVVM Hooking up nested child views to child view model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, nested

I'm trying to institute nested ViewModels in my already working application which uses nested views.  Here's an example of what I want to do:

MainWindow View:

```
<Window x:Name="FCTWindow" x:Class="CatalogInterface.MainWindow"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="532">

    <Window.Resources>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel.DirFilesListBoxViewModel}" x:Name="BodyGridLeft" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <local:ctlDirFilesListBox>
            <!--
                Need to access the `ItemsSource="{Binding }"` and
                 `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=}"` of the ListBox in 
                 `ctlDirFilesListBox` view -->
        </local:ctlDirFilesListBox>
</Window>
```

Child View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CatalogInterface.ctlDirFilesListBox"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

<Grid x:Name="MainControlGrid">           
    <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBoxItem_SelectionChanged" 
                         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFFFF"
                         Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_KeyDown"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindowViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace CatalogInterface.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public DirFilesViewModel DirFilesViewModel { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            DirFilesViewModel = new DirFilesViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

So, I need to hook `ListBox.SelectedItem` and `ListBox.ItemSource` to bind with properties in `MainWindowViewModel.DirFilesViewModel`.  The catch is I have to do the binding in `MainWindow View` not `ctlDirListBox` view.

How do i access elements inside my child view?  I think that's my biggest barrier.  I think all my data context is right, I just can't wrangle the child view elements.

Comment: UserControls should be designed for your models or your view models. You should NOT design a view model for your UserControl. Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel? **No,** and there's a very good reason why. For a real life example of this anti-pattern and why it fails so hard read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729258/1228).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that `DirFilesViewModel` is the viewmodel for that usercontrol. If that's not the case, let me know what the real situation is and we'll get it sorted out.

This is a very simple case. @JamieMarshall If the XAML you provided is all there is to your UserControl, maybe it shouldn't be a usercontrol at all. You could just write a DataTemplate with that XAML in it and use that, or you could write a Style for ListBox. If you need the events, then a UserControl makes sense, but you may not actually need the events.

But it could just be a minimal example to understand how UserControls are used, and for that purpose it's well suited.

You can assign an instance of your main viewmodel to the main window's DataContext in the window's constructor,

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
}
```

or in the XAML as

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainWindowViewModel />
<Window.DataContext>
```

Neither is particularly preferable, just don't do either one in a UserControl. Your main window is pretty much the only time a view (a window is a view, properly considered) should create its own viewmodel.

Making it a resource doesn't add anything. Your binding to Grid.DataContext is a bad idea -- it's rare that you ever bind anybody's DataContext to anything; this is related to what Will was talking about in your other question -- but even if it were a good idea, this is what the binding would look like:

```
<Grid
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
    >
```

But don't do that!

One thing you can do to display that usercontrol with the correct data is create "implicit datatemplates" for your your viewmodels that'll be displayed in parents like this one.

For example:

App.xaml

```
<!-- No x:Key, just DataType: It'll be implicitly used for that type. -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DirFilesViewModel>
    <local:ctlDirFilesListBox />
</DataTemplate>
```

Then in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<UserControl 
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Content="{Binding DirFilesViewModel}" 
    />
```

XAML will go to the window's DataContext for a property named `DirFilesViewModel`. What it finds there is an object that's an instance of the class also named `DirFilesViewModel`. It knows it has a DataTemplate for that class, so it uses that datatemplate.

This is amazingly powerful: Imagine you have an `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` with thirty instances of ten different kinds of viewmodels with different views, and the user selects one or another. The selected viewmodel is in a mainviewmodel property named `SelectedChildVM`. Here's the XAML to display SelectedChildVM with the correct view:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedChildVM}" />
```

That's it.

Moving along:

```
        <!--
            Need to access the `ItemsSource="{Binding }"` and
             `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=}"` of the ListBox in 
             `ctlDirFilesListBox` view -->
```

No you don't! That's the last thing you want to do! Some UserControls have properties of their own, instead of a viewmodel. With those, you bind the properties in the parent like any control.

This is a different use case of UserControls: It's "parameterized" by inheriting a viewmodel as its DataContext. The information you give it is the viewmodel.

The controls in the UserControl should have their own bindings, where they get that stuff from properties of the UserControl's viewmodel.

Let's assume the usercontrol's viewmodel (I'm guessing that's what `DirFilesViewModel` is) has a `Files` property (`ObservableCollection<SomeFileClass>`) and a `SelectedFile` class (`SomeFileClass`). You likely don't need `ListBoxItem_SelectionChanged`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="CatalogInterface.ctlDirFilesListBox"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:CatalogInterface.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid x:Name="MainControlGrid">           
    <ListBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile}"
        SelectionChanged="ListBoxItem_SelectionChanged" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
        Background="#FFFFFF"
        Grid.Row="2" 
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
        BorderThickness="0"
        >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
                <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_KeyDown"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ed Plunkett, this is a very comprehensive answer.  One question though - the DataTemplate trick is cool, but what if I wanted to go basic.  How would I explicitly reference the child view model without binding data context?  This is just for my own edification.  I'll probably end up using your trick, it's hard to appreciate a Ferrari if you've never been in a Pinto.  :)

Comment: @JamieMarshall I wouldn't call it a "trick", exactly; that's like saying it's a "trick" to get around a curve with the steering wheel instead of drifting. DataTemplates aren't necessarily implicit: You can give them an `x:Key` attribute and use them as the `ItemTemplate` of a ListBox or ItemsControl, or explicitly tell a contentcontrol which one to use: `<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />`.

Comment: If you've got an implicit datatemplate for a viewmodel (say, to edit its properties), maybe you also have one or more explicit ones, for example if you have a list of the viewmodel in a ListBox, and you just want to display the `Name` property. Or you might have a readonly  view, a compact view, etc. etc. WPF is a different way of thinking about UI from winforms/MFC/etc. You have to learn to think like WPF.

Comment: @JamieMarshall If the XAML you provided is all there is to your UserControl, maybe it shouldn't be a usercontrol at all. You could just write a DataTemplate with that XAML in it and use that, or you could write a Style for ListBox. If you need the events, then a UserControl makes sense, but you may not actually need the events.

Comment: alight I think I'm onboard.  To summarize - your saying I should always set my `DataContext` using `DataTemplate` and never (with exception) set directly bind the `DataContext`directly.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i access elements inside my child view?

You could add two dependency properties (for example named `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem`) to the code-behind class of your `ctlDirFilesListBox` control and bind to these in the parent window:

```
<local:ctlDirFilesListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Property}" SelectedItem="{Binding Property}" />
```

You should also bind to these properties in the `UserControl`:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBoxItem_SelectionChanged" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FFFFFF"
                 Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderThickness="0"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="ListBoxItem_MouseDoubleClick"/>
            <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="ListBoxItem_KeyDown"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
public class ctlDirFilesListBox : UserControl
{
    //...

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ctlDirFilesListBox));

    public IEnumerable ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(ctlDirFilesListBox));

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }
}
```