# WPF Binding TabControl TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am relatively new to MVVM in WPF and have been trying to solve an issue for several days now.  I am using the dragablz tab control and binding the ItemsSource which is an ObservableList of objects.  The content of the Tab Item is a UserControl, however; its datacontext is `null`.  I've created a simple setup to demonstrate the issue I'm having:

**Model/ViewModel Classes:**

```
public class Item
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public ItemContent Body { get; set; }
}

public class ItemContent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }       
}
```

**Main Window XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTestApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication.ViewModels"
    xmlns:dragablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz;assembly=Dragablz"
    xmlns:dockablz="clr-namespace:Dragablz.Dockablz;assembly=Dragablz"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <views:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Click="btnAdd_Click" />
    <dockablz:Layout Grid.Row="1">
        <dragablz:TabablzControl HeaderMemberPath="Header" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedIndex="1">
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:Item}">
                    <local:TabItemControl />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>
    </dockablz:Layout>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**Tab Item XAML**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfTestApplication.TabItemControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:WpfTestApplication.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <views:ItemContent />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Body}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**And the btnAdd_Click event**

Note that I don't use this in my actual code but it was a fast and dirty way to add tab items dynamically without adding a command.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel)DataContext).Items.Add(new ViewModels.Item() { Header = "New One", Body = new ViewModels.ItemContent() { Name = "This One" } });
    }
```

Comment: `<UserControl.DataContext>
    <views:Item />
</UserControl.DataContext>` the heck is that?

Comment: Defining the DataContext for the UserControl.  I actually have it set to `<view:ItemContent />` now.

Comment: The data context should flow from the parent. Setting the DC inside of a usercontrol is a major code smell. Don't do it.  You shouldn't ever have to.

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729258/1228) detailing this common pitfall with UC design.

Comment: Okay, so I read your other answer and I **think** I understand.  So in my example above, I need a dependency property that accepts a ItemContent and will bind its properties to the correct places in my UserControl?  Then in my MainWindow xaml, I set that property with the Content object?

Comment: The DataContext of the UserControl will be whatever is in the Items collection of the main window view model.  Is that what you want?

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will answered my question in the comment to the original question. I used his answer to another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729258/1228 to do the following.

I removed this from my UserControl:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <views:ItemContent />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I then added a dependency property called `Body` to my UserControl code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BodyProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("Body", 
                            typeof(ViewModels.ItemContent), 
                            typeof(TabItemControl), 
                            new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ViewModels.ItemContent Body
{
    get
    {
        return (ViewModels.ItemContent)GetValue(BodyProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(BodyProperty, value);
    }
}

public string BodyText {
    get
    {
        return Body?.Name;
    }
    set
    {
        if (Body != null)
        {
            Body.Name = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I updated my MainWindow's Tab control ContentTemplate as such:

```
<dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:ItemContent}">
        <local:TabItemControl Body="{Binding Body}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</dragablz:TabablzControl.ContentTemplate>
```

And changed my UserControl to use the BodyText property for the value of the TextBox:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding BodyText}" />
</Grid>
```