# Sharing a viewmodel between views and using the EventAggregator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, eventaggregator

I have a system (using Prisim and MVVM)that has numerous Views used to collect data. Each View has its own ViewModel that currently sends data to a common data class.
I have been trying (without success) to create one ViewModel that could be used by all of these views to save constantly updating the common data class.
However I am running into difficulties as my shared ViewModel will need use of the EventAggregator. My shared ViewModel's constructor has (IEventAgreggator eventAggregator) as an argument. However when I attempt to bind my Views to this using:

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:DataViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```

I receive the error

> "DataViewModel does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument"

. Is there a way around this? I don't have this problem if I use  autowire but cant seem to share a ViewModel between Views this way. This is my first post so apologies if this is a dumb question.Thanks

Comment: Setting your DataContext inside your user control is usually a very bad idea.  UserControls should be designed for your models or your view models. You should NOT design a view model for your UserControl. Does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel? **No,** and there's a very good reason why. For a real life example of this anti-pattern and why it fails so hard read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729258/1228).

Answer (score 0):

Normally in PRISM based application we register out ViewModels in the container so that they can be auto resolved via DI container.

You need to make sure that you are registering your newly created ViewModel type in container in the Module Initialize method.

We have normally Unity container in our apps and we have to do something like below in the Module `Initialize` method.

```
Container.RegisterType<DataViewModel >(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
public Myusercontrol ()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     DataViewModel vm = new DataViewModel (eventAggregator);
     this.DataContext = vm;
}
```

Comment: I still receive an error on InitializeCompent(); of 
'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: Please can  you share some more details and How to initialize object.